# Ordenar de forma descendente objeto em javaScript

Tags: javascript, objetos

Preciso ordenar de forma descendente o seguinte objeto e após isso devo excluir tudo o que vier depois do "_" e inclusive ele, para ver qual a palavra é formada:

Segue o que já fiz:

```
var str = 'string muito grande para o comentário';
var count = {};

str.split('').forEach(function(v) {

 if (v === ' ') return;
 v = v.toLowerCase();
 count[v] = count[v] ? count[v] + 1 : 1; 

}); 

console.log(count);


count{
    a:94 
    b:93
    c:88
    d:87
    e:91
    f:86
    g:80
    h:83
    i:78
    j:79
    k:82
    l:92
    m:74
    n:99
    o:96
    p:98
    q:84
    r:97
    s:77
    t:81
    u:100
    v:95
    w:75
    x:89
    y:85
    z:76
    _:90
}
```

Comment: Ta com cara de dever de casa isso dai... o que você ja fez? Onde esta a sua dúvida?

Comment: Apenas contei quantas vezes cada letra aparecia nesta string isto e cheguei naquele resultado, mas agora preciso fazer o que está ali na descrição da pergunta. Cheguei nisso dessa forma:


var str = 'string muito grande para o comentário';
var count = {};
str.split('').forEach(function(v) {
    if (v === ' ') return;
    v = v.toLowerCase();
    count[v] = count[v] ? count[v] + 1 : 1;
})

console.log(count);

Comment: Coloca esse seu código do comentário lá na pergunta

Comment: @SabrinaB. Coloquei uma resposta baseado no comentário. Ideal é esse seu código ser adicionado na pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como seu intuito final é obter a palavra, basta utilizar a função abaixo:

```js
var str = 'string muito grande para o _ comentário'; 
var count = {}; 


str.split('').forEach(function(v) { 
 if (v === ' ') 
  return; 
 v = v.toLowerCase(); 
 count[v] = count[v] ? count[v] + 1 : 1; 
}) 

function palavra(hashTable){
  return Object.keys(hashTable).sort(function(a, b){
    //Ordenacao decrescente
    return hashTable[b] - hashTable[a];

  }).reduce(function(p, c){ 
      //Formacao da palavra
      return p+c
  }).split('_')[0];//Texto antes de _
  
}

console.log(palavra(count))
```

Comment: Realmente funcionou, eu fiz o teste de mesa está correto. Muito obrigada!

Comment: @SabrinaB. Então, marca minha resposta como certa, por favor.